# Github personal access token not working in api request call in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, github

Trying to use Personal access token while calling github apis to overcome rate limit. I am able to get results till some point like till i reach rate limit. After that I am getting 403 forbidden error even though I am using PAT. I am using the token as shown below. After some time I am able to retrieve the results like rate limit getting reset.

```
let request  = require('got')

const header = {
    json: true,
    headers: {'user-agent': 'aws'},
    Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
    Authorization: "token 989842948hbf24424244"
}

 let closedPRUrlResult = await request(closedPRUrl, header);
    console.log(closedPRUrlResult.body.total_count);
```

What is the right way of using PAT in header while making a get call?

```
error null
(node:47848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HTTPError: Response code 403 (Forbidden)
    at EventEmitter.emitter.on (/Users/username/Desktop/Automate/node_modules/got/source/as-promise.js:74:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:47848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, check if your query is missing a [valid `User-Agent` header](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required)

> We request that you use your GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the `User-Agent` header value.
>   This allows us to contact you if there are problems.
>
> If you provide an invalid User-Agent header via cURL (or via an alternative client), you will receive a `403 Forbidden` response.